# Can't get modernizr to work with IE at all

Tags: css, html, drupal-6, modernizr

I have a website on drupal-6, I downloaded modernizr library and module and did the rest to get modernizr working, and it seems like working in firebug and the js files load in IE but doesn't do anything, for example in  it doesn't show background image that I set. I already tried display: block; thing, dont know what else to do. thanks

Comment: You need to show what you actually did. A piece of code, or a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's loading in your head before other scripts. This should ensure proper functionality.

Comment: modernizr is one script that is essential to be in your head and add the class no-js to your html tag. <html class="no-js"> http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/how-to-use-modernizr/

Comment: and yes it even loads before God himself, it's in the head, thanks for the answer though